# printing on screen and a text file

Tags: c, text, tee

I need to dump the certain things into a text file and same has needs to be displayed on screen. (I'm telling about a C program utiltiy)
The menu option looks like following,

```
1. display AA parameters
2. display BB parameters
3. display CC parameters
4. dump all
5. Exit
Select option >
```

If they select 1/2/3, it just needs to displayed on screen only or if they select option #4,it need to display all the parameters one by one and same needs to dumped in a .txt file.

I know, we can use the printf and fprintf functions to display on screen and write it to text file respectively. The thing is that I've display more that 20 parameters and each have at least 20 sub-parameters.

I'm currently implemented as below,

```
printf (        "Starting serial number       [%ld]\n", 
        serial_info_p->start_int_idx);
fprintf(file_p, "Starting serial number       [%ld]\n", 
        serial_info_p->start_int_idx)
printf (        "Current Serial number         [%d]\n", 
        serial_info_p->current_int_idx);
fprintf(file_p, "Current Serial number         [%d]\n", 
        serial_info_p->current_int_idx);
```

Is there an easiest way to implement this to cut down the number of lines of code?

Comment: I assume, just a simple pipe through tee is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go more radical than what people have suggested so far, but maybe it is too much for you.  (The 'inline' keyword is C99; you can omit it without much consequence if you code to C89.)

```
/*
** These could be omitted - unless you get still more radical and create
** the format strings at run-time, so you can adapt the %-24s to the
** longest tag you actually have.  Plus, with the strings all here, when
** you change the length from 24 to 30, you are less likely to overlook one!
*/
static const char fmt_int[]  = "%-24s [%d]\n";
static const char fmt_long[] = "%-24s [%ld]\n";
static const char fmt_str[]  = "%-24s [%s]\n";   /* Plausible extra ... */

static inline void print_long(FILE *fp, const char *tag, long value)
{
    fprintf(fp, fmt_long, tag, value);
}

static inline void print_int(FILE *fp, const char *tag, int value)
{
    fprintf(fp, fmt_int, tag, value);
}

static inline void print_str(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const char *value)
{
    fprintf(fp, fmt_str, tag, value);
}

static void dump_data(FILE *fp, const serial_info_t *info)
{
    dump_long("Starting serial number", info->start_int_idx);
    dump_int( "Current Serial number",  info->current_int_idx);
    /* ... and similar ... */
}
```

Then the calling code would call `dump_data()` once (with argument `stdout`) for options 1, 2, 3 and twice (once with `stdout`, once with file pointer for output file) for option 4.

If the number of parameters got truly huge (into the multiple hundreds), I'd even go as far as to consider a data structure which encoded type and offset information (`offsetof` from `<stddef.h>`) and pointers to functions and such like, so that there would be just a loop in `dump_data()` iterating over a structure which encodes all the necessary information.

You could also simplify life by using the same basic integer type (`long` in your example) for all the integer members of the data structure.

Fred Brooks in "Mythical Man Month" - a book well worth reading if you've not already done so, but make sure you read the Twentieth Anniversary edition - says in Chapter 9:

> Show me your flowcharts [code] and conceal your tables [data structures], and I shall continue to be mystified. Show me your tables, and I won't usually need your flowcharts; they'll be obvious.

A table-driven version of this code could end up saving space, as well as frustration when having to change a hundred related functions in the same way whereas a simple change in the tabular data could have fixed the whole lot.

Answer (score 6):

*Edit: <strike>the C++ tag seems misleading, can someone remove it please?</strike> thanks :)*

I use variadic macros to customize printf and friends.

I would write something like this:

```
#define     tee(fp,fmt, ...)                             \
        {                                                \
                printf (fmt, __VA_ARGS__);               \
                fprintf (fp, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);          \
        }
```

(the name comes from the tee(1) utility)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this allows you to add any number of output streams, and allows changing them at runtime simply by modifying the PrintTarget linked list.

```
/** gcc -Wall -o print_target print_target.c && ./print_target */
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PrintTarget* PrintTargetp;

void* xmalloc (size_t size);
PrintTargetp pntCreate (PrintTargetp head, FILE* target);
void pntDestroy (PrintTargetp list);

typedef struct PrintTarget
{
  FILE* target;
  PrintTargetp next;
} PrintTarget;

void myPrintf (PrintTargetp streams, char* format, ...)
{
  va_list args; 
  va_start(args, format);
  while (streams)
    {
      vfprintf(streams->target, format, args);
      streams = streams->next;
    }
  va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
  PrintTargetp streams = pntCreate(NULL, stdout);
  streams = pntCreate(streams, fopen("somefile.txt", "a+")); //XXX IO errors?

  myPrintf(streams, "blah blah blah...\n");
  pntDestroy(streams);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's a definition of auxiliary functions:

```
PrintTargetp pntCreate (PrintTargetp head, FILE* target)
{
  PrintTargetp node = xmalloc(sizeof(PrintTarget));
  node->target = target;
  node->next   = head;
  return node;
} 

void pntDestroy (PrintTargetp list)
{
  while (list) 
    {
      PrintTargetp next = list->next;
      free(list);
      list = next;
      //XXX cycles?
      //XXX close files?
    }
}

void* xmalloc (size_t size)
{
  void* p = malloc(size);
  if (p == NULL)
    {
      fputs("malloc error\n", stderr);
      abort();
    }
  return p;
}
```

Comment: A small functions `PrintTarget* pnt_create(PrintTarget* head, FILE* target)` and `void pnt_destroy(PrintTarget* list)` wouldn't hurt.

Comment: That's a really good algorithm.  Although, I'm not sure if it would help cut down on the lines of code since the problem only involves two different output streams.  Regardless, it's a well-constructed solution.

Comment: @Josh: I've added sample definitions of `pntCreate()`, `pntDestroy()`. Feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just pipe the output of your prorgam to the [`tee(1)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(unix)) command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a console application, you should be able to output to the screen (standard output) using something like:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Hello World\n");
```

This should enable you to move the code that prints your data to its own function, and to pass in a FILE* for it to print to.  Then the function can print to the screen if you pass "stdout", or to a file if you pass in a different FILE*, e.g.:

```
void print_my_stuff(FILE* file) {
    fprintf( file,"Starting serial number       [%ld]\n", serial_info_p->start_int_idx);
    fprintf(file, "Current Serial number         [%d]\n", serial_info_p->current_int_idx);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I didn't notice you needed a C solution. I'll leave this answer for reference, but it obviously requires C++.

You could create a new stream class that sends the output to two streams. I found an implementation of this at http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~imaman/programs/teestream.html. I haven't tried it, but it should work.

Here's the code from the link:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template<typename Elem, typename Traits = std::char_traits<Elem> >
struct basic_TeeStream : std::basic_ostream<Elem,Traits>
{
   typedef std::basic_ostream<Elem,Traits> SuperType;

   basic_TeeStream(std::ostream& o1, std::ostream& o2) 
      :  SuperType(o1.rdbuf()), o1_(o1), o2_(o2) { }

   basic_TeeStream& operator<<(SuperType& (__cdecl *manip)(SuperType& ))
   {
      o1_ << manip;
      o2_ << manip;
      return *this;
   }

   template<typename T>
   basic_TeeStream& operator<<(const T& t)
   {
      o1_ << t;
      o2_ << t;
      return *this;
   }

private:
   std::ostream& o1_;
   std::ostream& o2_;
};

typedef basic_TeeStream<char> TeeStream;
```

You would use it like this:

```
ofstream f("stackoverflow.txt");
TeeStream ts(std::cout, f);
ts << "Jon Skeet" << std::endl; // "Jon Skeet" is sent to TWO streams
```

Comment: Oh god, the world does NOT need any more Zapp Branigan.  One is too many.

Comment: @Adam, what about two Jon Skeets? I don't know if Stack Overflow could handle that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

FILE *f = fopen("somefile.txt", "a+");
FILE *fp[] = { stdout, f };
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN(fp); i++) {
    fprintf(fp[i], "Starting serial number [%ld]\n", serial_info_p->start_int_idx);
    fprintf(fp[i], "Current serial number [%ld]\n", serial_info_p->start_int_idx);
}

fclose(f);
```